# Fit 9 pics matrix on screen

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have 9 pictures that I want to display on screen so they take maximum space and I don't have scrollbars. I want to display them in 3*3 matrix. 
I don't know what the size will be, but all 9 will be the same size.

How do I do this?

Comment: just put them in and style the img tag to 33% width float right or float left. Try it and come back with real problem

Comment: buy a jquery plug-in for $10

Comment: @Farrukh Subhani Not really, sometimes the screen width is less than the screen height. Or when the height is really small, you will get scroll bars

Comment: @DanielCheng doesn't matter, 33% width & height would work perfectly. Bonus points for using divs with background images, and `background-size: cover;` to maintain aspect ratios.

Comment: Oh I was thinking about 9 squares and that they do not stretch across the entire screen.

Comment: wouldn't it reflow if I resize the browser?

Comment: @RomanHoyenko No, because they're 33% width. Try it before guessing what would happen, and come back with any problems.

Comment: ok, let me try, thanks guys, for some reason I was making complicated solutions trying to figure out screen size, picture sizes, etc.

Comment: Why does this require to have images as background in CSS

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I made a jsFiddle and decided to put it as an answer anyway.

Set the body and html to `height: 100%;`

```
html, body {
    height: 100%;
}
```

And have 9 divs with background images floated left, with 33.3333% width and height.

```
div {
    width: 33.3333%;
    height: 33.3333%;
    float: left;
}
```

And that's all there is to it!

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/D9WGv/

Comment: Is there a way to keep the full picture in there when I resize? Right now it just cuts the excess.

Comment: That way you may have thick borders at the top and bottom, or left and right. In other words, the images do not fill the screen.

Comment: Use `background-size: contain;`. That will add borders, as Daniel mentioned. Or use `background-size: 100% 100%;` That will stretch the image. It's a responsive design, so it's impossible to maintain the aspect ratio without cropping, distorting, or adding borders.